# Clojure idiomatic get-and-set function

Tags: clojure

Is there a more idiomatic/readable way of writing a get-and-set function in Clojure than:

```
(def the-ref (ref {}))

(defn get-and-set [new-value]
  (dosync
    (let [old-value @the-ref]
     (do
       (ref-set the-ref new-value)
       old-value))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the simple cases I tend to see this operation used directly instead of wrapped in a function:

```
hello.core> (dosync (some-work @the-ref) (ref-set the-ref 5))
5
```

In this case **`dosync` generally serves as the wrapper** you are looking for. within the `dosync` This is significant because dosync composes nicely with other transactions and makes the bounds of the transaction visible.  If you are in a position where the wrapper function can completely encapsulate all the references to the ref then perhaps refs are not the best tool.

A typical use of refs could look more along these lines:

```
(dosync (some-work @the-ref @the-other-ref) (ref-set the-ref @the-other-ref))
```

The need to wrap it is rare because when ref's are used they typically are use in groups of more than one ref because coordinated changes are required by the problem at hand. In cases where their is just one value then atoms are more common.

Comment: The reason for the get-and-set is that I want to do batch processing of the value that is currently on the ref. The ref is actually a map of refs, which several threads update concurrently. As the batch processing involves some io, I think I need to do it outside the transaction, so I need to get the current value of the ref and I reset it in an atomic way.

Comment: any transactions in the refs within the ref will be part of one large transaction because dosyncs absorb inner transactions. the official way to have side effects and blocking operations work in refs is to send them to an agent from the ref. Refs guarantee to only send once and only with the results as actually committed to the result. if the transaction aborts the messages are not sent.

Comment: atoms or agents may make your life a little easier for this problem.

Comment: Arthur, sending the batch to an agent is indeed a very very nice idea. Thanks a lot!